# pairing data from 1 table query myql with complex rule

Tags: mysql, database, view, pairing

I have data like this : with the data divided into role id , role id 1 is the participant and role id 2 is the evaluator,

Each evaluator will get the same number of participants but its canot be pair if in same departement

```
|id| Name | roleid | departement |
|---------------------------------
|1 |  a   |  1     |   xx        |
|---------------------------------
|2 |  b   |  1     |   yy        |
|---------------------------------
|3 |  c   |  1     |   zz        |
|---------------------------------
|4 |  d   |  1     |   xx        |
|----------------------------------
|5 |  e   |  1     |   yy        |
|---------------------------------
|6 |  f   |  2     |   xx        |
|----------------------------------
|7 |  g   |  2     |   yy        |
|---------------------------------
|8 |  h   |  2     |   zz        |
```

how to evenly match the data based on the roleid but it's canot be mattch in same departement

so I will insert this data into a table and I expect results like this :

```
  | id | participant_id | evaluator_id | participan_departemen  | evaluator_departemen |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1  |  1             |  7          |  xx                     |    yy                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 2  |  2             |  6          |  yy                     |    xx                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 3  |  3             |  7          |  zz                     |    yy                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 4  |  4             |  8          |  xx                     |    zz                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 5  |  5             |  6          |  yy                     |    xx                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OR

the result can be :

```
  | id | participant_id | evaluator_id | participan_departement  | evaluator_departement |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1  |  1             |  8          |  xx                     |    zz                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 2  |  2             |  8          |  yy                     |    zz                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 3  |  3             |  6          |  zz                     |    xx                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 4  |  4             |  7          |  xx                     |    yy                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 5  |  5             |  6          |  yy                     |    xx                |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

all possible pairs can be between evaluators and participants but can't be paired if it's in same department

somebody help me for write like query bellow :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  roleid INT,
  departement VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 1, 'a', 1, xx );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 2, 'b', 1, yy );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 3, 'c', 1, zz );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 4, 'd', 1, xx );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 5, 'e', 1, yy );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 6, 'f', 2, xx );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 7, 'g', 2, yy );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 8, 'h', 2, zz );

SELECT 0,b.user_id AS participant_id,a.user_id AS evaluator_id, a.id_departement AS participan_departemen, b.id_departement AS evaluator_departemen
    FROM (
      SELECT user_id,departement, @RN := @RN + 1 AS RN
      FROM `user`
      JOIN (SELECT @RN := 0) AS r
      WHERE role_id = 1 
    ) a
    JOIN (
      SELECT user_id,departement, @RN2 := @RN2 + 1 AS RN
      FROM `user`
      JOIN (SELECT @RN2 := 0) AS r
      WHERE role_id = 2 
    ) b
    JOIN (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts
      FROM `user`
      WHERE role_id = 2
    ) c
    WHERE a.RN % c.counts = b.RN - 1
    AND a.departement<> b.departement
```

Comment: Should it be something like : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/usu3XK7Gn8gGqQnusmCiLk/7 .

Comment: I do not understand why  evaluator_id  = 7 when participant_id  =1 in your first result table

Comment: @Ergast basha : it's just random pairing